# Android: Dialog cut from Top when activity is resumed

Tags: android

I display a custom dialog which is shown proper on show. But after that when I press home key and bring the application in background. Next, I again launch the application from task menu but in that case the image is cut from the top.

Proper Dialog  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxejG.png)

Dialog Clipped From Top  [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sg8uJ.png)

Can any one help us in identifying why it must be cutting from top.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is happening, but you could try a forceLayout() or invalidate() in your onResume() and it may help ?

Comment: I've just encountered the same issue. Did you solve, ignore, or work around the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with Kitkat/Lollipop versions I think. It can be fixed with the following code.

```
    // Only for Api >=4.0
    // On Kitkat & Lollipop, layout top gets clipped if this code is not there.
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
```